# Can a kink in a finite one dimensional box tunnel into a trivial solution?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-tunneling, instantons, solitons, sine-gordon

Given a simple kink solution of the [Sine Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine-Gordon_equation), is it possible for such a solution in a finite volume to tunnel into a trivial vacuum solution, given that such tunneling demands a finite amount of energy?
(the argument that forbids such transition is based on topological charge conservation, but I can't understand why the topological charge should be conserved also quantum mechanically, specially in a finite box)

---

[Periodic solutions to the D=1+1 SG system](https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:ecb19abb-03ec-3988-9b12-d10c46c9d364)
According to this paper there are spatially periodic solutions to the SG equation so consequently kink-like solutions can be defined in a finite box. The question would be then, can anybody please compute the amplitude of the decay of such finite volume kink into a trivial solution in terms of the spatial period?

Comment: Who says it should be conserved in a finite box?

Comment: I'm sure in the case of a time-independent kink in an infinitely large box, the topological charge forbids the kink to decay into a trivial vacuum solution. The argument in the book by Shifman(Advanced topics in QFT) is that it demands an infinite amount of energy.
Also Coleman's lectures(1979), it is argued very clearly that the kink can not be transformed into a trivial vacuum solution under the classical equation of motion(time evolution.) But what if one is concerned with the quantum mechanical kink?
Rajaraman page 155 is trying to show the same thing in the quantum case.@Qmechanic

Comment: I'm curious if such tunneling is possible then how can I compute the amplitude in terms of the size of the box perhaps by path integral or any other method? @Qmechanic

Comment: Wait, is it possible at all to define a kink in a finite box? or does it necessarily demand an infinitely large one?!

Comment: I found this and it ensures that at the very least there are spatially periodic solutions for SG system, so it can be defined in a finite box: https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:ecb19abb-03ec-3988-9b12-d10c46c9d364 @Qmechanic